# Issue with https with webHttpBinding

Tags: wcf

I am facing problem while implementing https with webHttpBinding. I am getting below error

Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]

Below is my web.config code. Please help

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpMobile" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>

  <service behaviorConfiguration="mybehavior"          name="SoIn.Services.MobileWebRole.Command">
    <endpoint address="mobile" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding"    bindingConfiguration="webHttpMobile" contract="SoIn.Services.MobileWebRole.ICommand" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="mybehavior" name="SoIn.Services.MobileWebRole.Query">
    <endpoint address="mobile" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpMobile" contract="SoIn.Services.MobileWebRole.IQuery" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="mybehavior" name="SoIn.Services.MobileWebRole.Configuration">
    <endpoint address="mobile" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpMobile" contract="SoIn.Services.MobileWebRole.IConfiguration" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="mybehavior">
      <serviceMetadata  httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Comment: what error message you are getting?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try below mentioned configuration.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpMobile" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>

  <service behaviorConfiguration="mybehavior"          name="SoIn.Services.MobileWebRole.Command">
    <endpoint address="mobile" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding"    bindingConfiguration="webHttpMobile" contract="SoIn.Services.MobileWebRole.ICommand" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="mybehavior" name="SoIn.Services.MobileWebRole.Query">
    <endpoint address="mobile" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpMobile" contract="SoIn.Services.MobileWebRole.IQuery" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="mybehavior" name="SoIn.Services.MobileWebRole.Configuration">
    <endpoint address="mobile" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpMobile" contract="SoIn.Services.MobileWebRole.IConfiguration" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="mybehavior">
      <serviceMetadata  httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Comment: i copied and pasted what u have given, but still not working... now i m getting problem with this tag which u have mentoied  <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />

Comment: do i have to implement mexHttpsBinding and webHttpsBinding ?

Comment: You can try that as well. Do you have <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true" />? It must be inside binding configuration.

Comment: I don't see how this is helpful, it does not explain anything. If I could, I would vote down.